# How to use the picklist values on email

Tags: email, email-template, fields

I am facing the problem on sending email.In our org we are using Picklist (Multi-Select) value for product.I need to mention the product are selected by user in email body.For example,User A selected TV,Laptop then i send the mail like "Hi A,
Thank you for choosing product TV,Laptop from our website.Our customer care person get back to for further details.

Comment: what is the issue. you can simply store the values into string and get those values in controller. Can you pls elaborate more?

Comment: @Ratan, My issue is i need to show the picklist value in email template. I want to show the value of multi picklist. For example, Hi xxx, You will order the "PC,TV". But now i can show the single value of Picklist. Now i sent the multiple mail for the user but it is not correct.Because customer is same but product only changed i need to merge the product and sent it by single mail.

Comment: so you are using multiselect picklist in email template? are you using setTargetobjectId and setWhatId for sending email?

Comment: I am using Picklist value. In my org we are using the clone option for change the product and the manufacture. So one customer can create the multiple product at a time.Once user choose the product i need to send the mail. In this condition i sending the separate mail for the same user(Product is different). I need to merge the product with single mail.

Comment: do you how to use visualforce email template?

Comment: @Ratan, Right now i am using the direct value.And i am using custom html template.

Comment: What do you mean direct value ? If you want to send only single email with multiple products name. Then you require batch process that will run every midnight and check which user select how many products then send email to all the users with there selected products.

Comment: Product Name   : {!home_application.Product__c}

Comment: you may require batch process that will send only one email to single user.

Comment: It send the multiple mail to same user,avoiding the multiple mail to same user. I need to add the all picklist in single mail.If it is possible???

Comment: If you care fully read your requirement. Then you can see User selected Product1 then send an email. Then User1 again select Product2 then send an email. So when user1 selected Product1 then we don't know if user will select product2 or not.  We can't track That. What we can do Once user selected all the products then click on any button that will send an email to user with all the selected products.

Comment: at final we need to trigger the mail ????

Comment: and how can i show the multiple value of user selected.

Comment: iterate over all the product selected by particular user and get all the product name and add into the email body.

Comment: i need this only. i dont know how to iterate over all product can you help me to solve my problem

Comment: Add your code in question.

Comment: Dear {!Account.Level_A__c},
File of {!homeapplication__c.Customer_Name__c} has been disbursed in following banks 
Product Name : {!homeapplication__c.homeapplication_Product__c}
City : {!Account.City__c}
Owner : {!Account__c.CreatedBy}
Disbursed Date : {!homeapplication__c.Disbursal_Date__c}

Comment: if there is any way to fetch all picklist value